# How can I pop a string?

Tags: python, string, list

I know that string is immutable in python. I'm trying to think a way that can pop the string like int.
For example:

```
   def remove(names: List[List[str]], name_to_remove: str) -> None
   """
   >>> name = ['Alpha', 'Bravo', 'Charlie', 'Delta']
   >>> remove(name, 'Charlie')
   >>> name #output
       ['Alpha', 'Bravo', 'Delta']
   """
```

What I've done but since str is immutable, the code is invalid:

```
   after_removing = [names]
        for lst in names:
            if name_to_remove in lst:
                after_removing.pop[name_to_remove]
```

How do I fix my code to get the example above? Thanks in advance

Comment: Strings being immutable is irrelevant here, since you're not changing a string, you're changing a list, which is mutable.

Comment: What do you mean by "pop the string like int"? Are `names` a list of lists like declared or a list of strings like in the test? What does it have to do with immutability?

Comment: Why is your function typed to accept a list of lists of strings, when in fact it just accepts a list of strings?

Comment: You said you know how to "*pop an `int`*". Please show us.

Comment: It sounds like you've written some code that doesn't work. Show us _that_ code. If you have a single string, say, `test = "AlphaBravoCharlie"`, you could remove all instances of "Bravo" with `test = test.replace("Bravo", "")`. The string is immutable, but its `replace` method returns a new string. I don't know if this is what you want of course.

Comment: Perhaps is just replacing `after_removing.pop[name_to_remove]` with `after_removing.remove(name_to_remove)`. You are changing the list, not the string.

Answer (score 1):

you can use

```
name.remove("alpha")
```

Comment: But strings don't have a "remove" method. Please explain _why_this would work.

Comment: His example is removing a string from a list. Not removing a string from a string.

Comment: Right, but several people are asking for clarification on that. It seems to me that the posted code as an example of a list operation poster wants replicated in a string.

Comment: It may well be that the string needs to be split into a list, popped or removed, and then converted back to a string.

Comment: unclear and no explanation.. not a good combination imo